# Netteza Millions of rows Loop and Calculate and Insert into New Table

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

I have been trying to loop through a Table with millions of rows in Netteza, calculate a measure (that itself takes significant amount of time since it is a loop) for every row and write it to a new table.

I am using insert into. But, it seems Netezza is too slow for this type of process! Are there any suggestions out there?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP"()
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS 
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE 
r record;
col2 int;
BEGIN

for r in select * from x    
Loop

col2 =  "SP_1"(r.q);
insert into some_table values(r.col1 , col2);
End Loop;

END;
END_PROC;
```

Comment: The procedural logic of a stored procedure runs in the host rather than the MPP backend. The way to get good performance is to move to a set processing model rather than a row-by-row model. That change would probably have to be made in SP_1. If you want to share the code for that we might be able to come up with something.

Comment: Thanks. Good point. I eventually had to change the SP_1 rather than row by row.